# Google analytics won't work in wordpress

Tags: code

I have a godaddy host and I am using wordpress platform using simple key theme.

In simplekey options - additionals it gives me option to add Additional Codes.. so I did add a code from google analytics but they won't work I even accepted all prof etc. Where should I add that code because I think that additional option won't work.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it resolves your problem..

Answer (score 1):

You can directly paste the google analytics code in your header.php or footer.php file which is present in your theme and it will work throughout the site.

Comment: I done this more than 24h ago and still it won't appear....

Comment: Do you see the code appearing in the page by viewing the source?

Comment: Yes, it appears...

Comment: You can check whether your google analytics code is working by browsing to the page of your website and then in a new tab go to the http://www.google.co.in/analytics/ to access your google analytics account and when you are inside, you can see your site folder..just click on website data and you will find the settings for real time tracking and when you click on that you will see that one visitor is there and thats you as you are in currently in page of the site..if you see 0 visitors or you dont find the site folder then it means you have not added the correct code for the correct domain..